# Exception occured: Illegal Argument - Argument 2, Object Expected (Making a Photoshop contact sheet using win32com)

Tags: python, photoshop, win32com

I'm trying to make a Photoshop contact sheet with the `MakeContactSheet` function included in Photoshop's API. It can be accessed using 'win32com.client'.

My first line:
`psApp = Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")`

Creates a `win32com.gen_py.E891EE9A-D0AE-4CB4-8871-F92C0109F18Ex0x1x0._Application._Application` object.

The class of this object seems to have all the available functions listed in the [documentation](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-vbs-ref.pdf) .

I then proceed to make a list of strings with os.walk.

`CSInputFiles = [path.join(r, f) for r, sd, fs in walk('C:\\Users\\chris\\Desktop\\1A') for f in fs]`

Then a mixed array of options:

`CSoptions = [True, psApp, False, False, 6, True, None, 0, 7, 4, 3, 300, 3, None, True]`

Finally I pass these arguments:
`psApp.MakeContactSheet(CSInpuFiles, CSoptions)`

Which seems to be right considering the function definition in `_Application`:

```
def MakeContactSheet(self, InputFiles=defaultNamedNotOptArg, Options=defaultNamedOptArg):
    'create a contact sheet from multiple files'
    # Result is a Unicode object
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1129599816, LCID, 1, (8, 0), ((12, 1), (12, 17)),InputFiles
        , Options)
```

Alas, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    psApp.MakeContactSheet(CSInputFiles, CSoptions)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\E891EE9A-D0AE-4CB4-8871-F92C0109F18Ex0x1x0\_Application.py", line 97, in MakeContactSheet
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1129599816, LCID, 1, (8, 0), ((12, 1), (12, 17)),InputFiles
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Adobe Photoshop', 'Illegal argument - argument 2\n- Object expected', None, 0, -2147220261), None)
```

My initial instinct was to convert all the string in my csInputFiles array to path objects with pathlib.

```
from pathlib import Path

CSInputFiles = [Path(path.join(r, f)) for r, sd, fs in walk('C:\\Users\\chris\\Desktop\\1A') for f in fs]
```

Which yielded this obscure piece of garbage when I passed the array to the function:

```
psApp.MakeContactSheet(CSInputFiles, CSoptions)

#RUN!

File "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    psApp.MakeContactSheet(CSInputFiles, CSoptions)
  File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\E891EE9A-D0AE-4CB4-8871-F92C0109F18Ex0x1x0\_Application.py", line 97, in MakeContactSheet
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1129599816, LCID, 1, (8, 0), ((12, 1), (12, 17)),InputFiles
TypeError: must be real number, not WindowsPath
```

Which doesn't make sense at all! How could it be expecting a real number? This is meant to be an array of input files!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error specified in the question was caused by the fact that I made the options argument a list as opposed to an object. For information about the structure of the object you can look [here](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/Photoshop/ContactSheetOptions.html#contactsheetoptions).

However after some asking around on GitHub I found that `MakeContactSheet` is a deprecated function as stated on page 19 of [this](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-vbs-ref.pdf) document.

This lead me develop a replacement of sorts using the pillow library.

The solution is to simply create an empty `png` and then paste all the images you want to put on your contact sheet onto that `png`.

I will paste a simplified version of this program, for the sake of solving the problem here.

```
from PIL import Image
from os import walk, path

#rows = amount of rows (int)
#columns = amount of clomns (int)
#sheetWidth = the width of the contact sheet in inch (int)
#sheetHeight = the height of the contact sheet in inch (int)
#aspectRatio = the simplified height to width ratio of the images on the contact sheet (height/width) (float)
#ppi = pixels per inch
#path = the folder containing all the images you wish to make a contact sheet of (string)

def make_contact_sheet(rows, columns, sheetWidth, sheetHeight, aspectRatio, ppi, filePath):

    #convert inches to pixels
    sheetWidth *= ppi
    sheetHeight *= ppi

    #Calculate the size that images will be on the sheet
    imageHeight = sheetHeight // columns
    imageWidth = int(imageHeight * aspectRatio)

    #Calculate how far apart the images will be spaced (I call this padding)
    xRemSpace = sheetWidth - (imageWidth * columns)
    xPad = xRemSpace // (columns-1)

    yRemSpace = sheetHeight - (imageHeight * rows)
    yPad = yRemSpace // (rows+1)

    #Now make the empty png
    sheet = Image.new("RGBA", (sheetWidth, sheetHeight), color=(0,0,0,255))

    #Loop through paths of the images and paste the images one by one
    x, y = 0, yPad
    images = [Image.open(path.join(r,f)) for r,sd,fs in walk(filePath) for f in fs]

    for i in range(len(images)):
        #Resize the image
        resized = images[i].resize((imageWidth, imageHeight))

        #Paste the images
        if i == 0:
            sheet.paste(resized, (x,y))
        elif i % columns == 0:
            x = 0
            y += imageHeight + yPad
            sheet.paste(resized, (x,y))
        else:
            x += imageWidth + xPad
            sheet.paste(resized, (x,y))

    return sheet

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sheet = make_contact_sheet(3, 5, 8, 5, (2/3), 300, r"Some path")
    sheet.show()
```

As stated above this is a very crude example, and it is based off a more elaborate version of the final program I wrote. But I've already overstepped the bounds of relevance.

Comment: If you do write an alternative solution in the future, please post a minimal example of the working code here, rather than a github link. Answers should be self-contained and not rely on external links (although if you have a link to documentation showing that the MakeContactSheet function was discontinued, that would be useful to add.